# Creating static cells in Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I'm trying to create static cells in a `UITableViewCell`. I've started by adding 2 cells in Interface Builder and given them the identifier `title` and `news`. Then I've created an array with these two identifiers and added it to `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. However I keep getting following error:

```
'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier title - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
```

The array

```
var menuItems = ["title", "news"]
```

`tableView` delegate methods

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 2
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 64
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(menuItems[indexPath.row], forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.2, alpha: 1.0)

    var bottomView: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, cell.frame.height-1, cell.frame.width, 1))
    bottomView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.2, alpha: 0.15)
    cell.contentView.addSubview(bottomView)

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating two cell at interfacebuilder?
Just create one as "title" or "news"

Comment: have you set the cell identifiers in interface builder?

Comment: yes i've set one to title and one to news

Comment: did you connect your subclass of ``UITableViewController`` with the tableViewController in interface builder?

Comment: yes i i've set the class to my tableViewController  (SideTableViewController)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you have to register the `UITableViewCell` class manually for the cell.
You can achieve this by calling

```
tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: menuItems[indexPath.row])
```

in either your `viewDidLoad()` function of in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function of `UITableViewDataSource`

Answer (score 1):

Like the error message describes, you must register them if you created them as an empty UI file. This can simply be placed in the viewDidLoad function.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var nib = UINib(nibName: "OrangeCell", bundle: nil)
        tableView.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "oranges")

        var nib2 = UINib(nibName: "AppleCell", bundle: nil)
        tableView.registerNib(nib2, forCellReuseIdentifier: "apples")
}
```

Comment: i dont have a nib file? why is that needed

Comment: @PeterPik it is only needed when you are using custom cells. If you are using standard ``UITableViewCell``s, try ``tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "YOUR_CELL_IDENTIFIER")``. Do this for both of your cell identifiers